# Convert a list of dictionary containing dictionaries into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following list of python dictionaries:

```
[{'date': '2019-02-21', 'basicStats': {'min': -0.9994264245033264, 'max': -0.41181543469429016, 'mean': -0.4983844268421697, 'stDev': 0.071324608484601}}, {'date': '2019-02-16', 'basicStats': {'min': -0.9990605711936951, 'max': -0.09592325985431671, 'mean': -0.385945735727586, 'stDev': 0.0640801258659954}}, {'date': '2019-02-01', 'basicStats': {'min': -0.9989479184150696, 'max': -0.21808761358261108, 'mean': -0.4007919550689754, 'stDev': 0.07135259658292871}}]
```

I want to convert it into a pandas dataframe with a column for date and more columns for 'min', 'max', 'mean' and 'stdev'. However, when I do:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

I get:

```
date                                         basicStats
0   2019-02-21  {'min': -0.9994264245033264, 'max': -0.4118154...
1   2019-02-16  {'min': -0.9990605711936951, 'max': -0.0959232...
2   2019-02-01  {'min': -0.9989479184150696, 'max': -0.2180876...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Do you expect a multi-index header or how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(d)
print (df)
        date  basicStats.min  basicStats.max  basicStats.mean  \
0  2019-02-21       -0.999426       -0.411815        -0.498384   
1  2019-02-16       -0.999061       -0.095923        -0.385946   
2  2019-02-01       -0.998948       -0.218088        -0.400792   

   basicStats.stDev  
0          0.071325  
1          0.064080  
2          0.071353
```

Another idea is expand dictionary - extract key `basicStats` and merge all another keys:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{**x, **x.pop('basicStats')}  for x in d])
print (df)
         date       min       max      mean     stDev
0  2019-02-21 -0.999426 -0.411815 -0.498384  0.071325
1  2019-02-16 -0.999061 -0.095923 -0.385946  0.064080
2  2019-02-01 -0.998948 -0.218088 -0.400792  0.071353
```